# Multiple Custom ListFragment in view pager

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a viewPager that include 3 different fragments with associated layouts (fragment_new_quiz, fragment_completed_quiz, fragment_created_quiz. Each one implements the onCreateView similarly like:

```
public class NewQuizFragment extends ListFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)     {
     super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_quiz, container, false);
     mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
     mArrayAdapter = new QuizAdapter(mItemList, getActivity());
     mArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
     setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
     return rootView;
  }
}
```

The layouts should all be different so I cannot reuse them. They are defined similarly to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fa6a6a"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/createButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Create" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/intro_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Created Quiz"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="299dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="No items."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I face is with this code configuration, eclipse gives me the error:

> list cannot be resolved or is not a field

related to this line

> mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

If however I change **any** of the 3 listview ids to something else in any of the 3 fragments, I don't get the compile time error. However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

> 11-16 16:32:52.533: E/AndroidRuntime(20935):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.list'.

I am kind of clueless about what to do. Is my usage of the various components not appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML, change these

```
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:id="@+id/android:empty"
```

to these:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:id="@android:id/empty"
```

In your Fragments, change

```
mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

to

```
mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

These are the proper ways to reference resource ids declared in the android namespace.

Comment: Cool! Learned something new. That solved it. Ill accept the answer when I can